# can't get endsWith(".java") to work

Tags: java

I am looping through all .jar files in a directory and looking to display the .jar filename and only ".java" filenames within the .jar in a dialog box.
I am almost correct, but all filenames within the .jar are displayed.
my working code is:

```
for (Enumeration em1 = jarfile.entries(); em1.hasMoreElements();)
{
    notes = Collections.list(em1);
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jarName + "\n" + notes);
```

---

When i try to weed out only the (".java") filenames, I can't get it right...

```
for (Enumeration em1 = jarfile.entries(); em1.hasMoreElements();)
{
    if(em1.endsWith(".java"))
    {
        notes = Collections.list(em1);
    }

}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jarName + "\n" + notes);
```

I'm hoping it's something syntaxtically stupid. I've tried many possibilities for hours. Can somebody can help me clear this up?

Comment: The type `Enumeration` does not have an `endsWith()` method.

Comment: first, you dont need to call collections.list in a loop. second, enumeration is not a string, so endsWith is not applicable to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use

```
for (Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> em1 = jarfile.entries();
         em1.hasMoreElements();)
{
  ZipEntry entry = em1.nextElement();      // Get a ZipEntry
  if(entry.getName().endsWith(".java")) {  // Get the name, should probably be
                                           // ".class"
    notes = Collections.list(em1);         // It does end with ".java".
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try turning it into a `String`.  That way you can use the `.endsWith(...)` method:

```
String value = (String) em1.nextElement();

if(value.endsWith(".java"))
{
    notes = Collections.list(em1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips everyone; none of the answers quite worked. I ended up using...

```
ArrayList<String> javalist = new ArrayList<String>();
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(jarName);
for (Enumeration list = zip.entries(); list.hasMoreElements(); )
{
                            ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) list.nextElement();
                            if(entry.getName().endsWith(".java"))
                            {    
                                //below line is the answer
                                javalist.add(entry.getName());
                            }
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jarName + "\n" + javalist);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is way old, but I just encountered this myself and this was high up in the search results. How I was able to check the extension was this:

```
fileName.toString().endsWith(extension);
```